# How many 5 digit even numbers can be formed such that all the digits are distinct?

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried solving it with dividing the question into 2 parts, even numbers ending with zero, and even numbers ending with rest of the  even numbers. With this approach I achieved 13776. Am I correct??

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt, not just your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that there are
9 possibilities for 1st place(except 0). Say you chose an integer from 1-9, call it a.
9 possibilities for 2nd place(you can’t choose a). Say you choose b. And so on for the rest.
So, number of 5 digit numbers = 9* 9* 8* 7* 6=27,216
Now, you have asked for even numbers. So let’s come from the back.
For the last digit, you have 5 possibilities. Second last=9 third last=8 fourth last=7 fifth last=6. This includes numbers starting with 0, ie. All numbers. We get 15,120
Now, fix the first digit as 0, so that we can eliminate non 5 digit possibilities. There are a total of 4* 8* 7* 6 = 1,344
So, the final answer=15,120-1344=13,776

Comment: +1, so both you and the OP agree.

Comment: So is my answer correct?

Comment: I was asleep sorry for the delay

Comment: Yes. If you are satisfied, mark as the answer.